# AJAX GET database columns from Table and populate Select Drop Down - items showing undefined

Tags: jquery, entity-framework-core, asp.net-ajax

I'm using AJAX to get items from a database table on the server to populate a drop down select list on my razor page.

The DB Table itself has far more columns than I actually want to return using AJAX.

I'm trying to simply pull only two of the columns from each row from the table, however in my attempt in doing this, the select drop down list shows the elements as undefined.

I have a similar AJAX request that works when I pull the whole table contents, but that particular table only has two columns anyway. In this scenario, I only need two columns from a large table and don't want to kill the efficiency of the application by pulling more data than needed to the web page.

Page Model:

```
 public IActionResult OnGetSelectAllMarkers()
    {
        var marker = _context.Marker
                 .Where(x => x.LayerGroupID == 1)
                 .Select(x => new
                 {
                     x.ID,
                     x.MarkerName,
                     // etc, we only include the columns we need for the query.
                 }).ToList();

        return new JsonResult(marker);
    }
```

AJAX:

```
 var options = {};
    options.url = "/Maps/Edit?handler=SelectAllMarkers";
    options.type = "GET";
    options.dataType = "json";
    options.success = function (data) {
        data.forEach(function (element) {
            $("#editMarkerSelect").append('<option value="' + element.ID + '">' + element.MarkerName + '</option>');
        });
        $('#editMarkerSelect option').clone().appendTo('#bindToMapObjectSelect');
    }
    options.error = function () {
        $("#editMarkerSelectMessageBar").html("Error while making Ajax call!");
        setTimeout(function () { $("#editMarkerSelectMessageBar").html(''); }, 5000);
    };
    $.ajax(options);
```

The items I want to retrieve using AJAX is simply the DB row ID and another column called MarkerName

The screenshot below shows I am pulling the correct items on the server, so there's something here that AJAX doesn't like, I don't get any errors in the browser de-bug tool so not sure how to diagnose this.

[image]

Update: I also tried the changes below, but still I find that AJAX sees the object array as undefined:

```
 public IActionResult OnGetSelectAllMarkers()
    {
        List<Marker> data = _context.Marker
                 .Where(x => x.LayerGroupID == 1)
                 .Select(x => new Marker
                 {
                     ID = x.ID,
                     MarkerName = x.MarkerName,
                     // etc, we only include the columns we need for the query.
                 }).ToList();

        return new JsonResult(data);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I finally figured out what was going on, two things. The OnGetSelectAllMarkers() method on my model page, shown in the first part of my question was wrong it appears. The method was returning a list with anonymous types and AJAX didn't seem to like that given the objects they were returning from the server were undefined.

The next part was the LINQ query was wrong. I was basing the WHERE statement on a column that sits half way across the table row, but tying to return a column value that is located before it. Didn't realize that would be an issue and only discovered this when trying to return a different column during the tests. After re-arranging the order of the columns in the table and updating as new migration, everything worked OK

Working code shown below:

```
 public IActionResult OnGetSelectAllMarkers()
    {
        List<Marker> data = _context.Marker
                 .Where(x => x.LayerGroupID == 1)
                 .Select(x => new Marker
                 {
                     ID = x.ID,
                     MarkerName = x.MarkerName,
                     // etc, we only include the columns we need for the query.
                 }).ToList();

        return new JsonResult(data);
    }

 var options = {};
    options.url = "/Maps/Edit?handler=SelectAllMarkers";
    options.type = "GET";
    options.dataType = "json";
    options.success = function (data) {
        data.forEach(function (element) {
            $("#editMarkerSelect").append('<option value="' + element.id + '">' + element.markerName + '</option>');
        });
        $('#editMarkerSelect option').clone().appendTo('#bindToMapObjectSelect');
    }
    options.error = function () {
        $("#editMarkerSelectMessageBar").html("Error while making Ajax call!");
        setTimeout(function () { $("#editMarkerSelectMessageBar").html(''); }, 5000);
        alert("error");
    };
    $.ajax(options);
```